# Distributed (asynchronous) averaging

Tags: python, graph, concurrency, simulation, statistics

This code simulates a distributed averaging protocol. There is a network of nodes, and at the clicks of a Poisson process:

1. A random node wakes up
2. Transmits it's current average to all the nodes it is connected to
3. These nodes have a coroutine which waits to accept new values and compute the average.

```
from numpy.random import exponential, randint, uniform
import time
from itertools import product


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.friends = []
        self.count = 0
        self.val = number
        self.average = number
        self.avg = self.averager()
        self.avg.next()

    def averager(self):
        while True:
            term = yield self.average
            self.val += term
            self.count += 1
            self.average = self.val/self.count


class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, num_nodes):
        self.nodes = [0]*num_nodes
        for i in range(num_nodes):
            self.nodes[i] = Node(randint(1, 10))
        self.set_connections()

    def set_connections(self):
        for f, g in product(self.nodes, self.nodes):
            p = uniform()
            if p < 0.8:
                f.friends.append(g)
                g.friends.append(f)

    def mainloop(self):
        num_nodes = len(self.nodes)
        while True:
            next_time = exponential(0.1)
            node = self.nodes[randint(num_nodes)]
            for friend in node.friends:
                friend.avg.send(node.average)
                print friend.average
            time.sleep(next_time)
```

So far I've only tested it as follows:

```
>>> n = Network(10)
>>> n.mainloop()
```

and then observed that the friend.average printed out all converge to the same value.

My main concern about this code is that a lot of the logic for waking up nodes is in the Network class, whilst I'd rather it was in the node class. Also, there's no exception/error handling, or proper testing.

The main purpose of this was to try and understand coroutines, which was a bit of a mind bender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the random graph is generated seems suspicious:

> ```
> class Network(object):
>     def __init__(self, num_nodes):
>         self.nodes = [0]*num_nodes
>         for i in range(num_nodes):
>             self.nodes[i] = Node(randint(1, 10))
>         self.set_connections()
>
>     def set_connections(self):
>         for f, g in product(self.nodes, self.nodes):
>             p = uniform()
>             if p < 0.8:
>                 f.friends.append(g)
>                 g.friends.append(f)
> ```

First of all, `self.nodes` should just be defined as

```
self.nodes = [Node(randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(num_nodes)]
```

The way that `nodes` changes type from a list of integers to a list of `Node` objects makes it feel slightly more dirty.

It looks like `set_connections()` is only meant to be called from the constructor, so it should be renamed `_set_connections()` to suggest that it is private.  However, considering that `__init__()` would just consist of two lines (`self.nodes = …` and `self._set_connections()`), I would just lump everything into `__init__()`.

`product(self.nodes, self.nodes)` seems wrong.  It's possible to cause a `Node` to befriend itself.  It's also possible to have two nodes list each other as friends twice.  I suspect that what you want is [`combinations(self.nodes, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
def __init__(self, num_nodes):
    self.nodes = [Node(randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(num_nodes)]
    for f, g in combinations(self.nodes, 2):
        if uniform() < 0.8:
            f.friends.append(g)
            g.friends.append(f)
```